# Qiskit QSVM - Alphas and Support Vectors

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I just started using Qiskit and I have implemented the QSVM example. However, I having trouble with the return. The `qsvm.predict()` results are reasonable but when trying to calculate the margin myself, this does not make sense. I was hoping someone could help me:

```
xData = qsvm_res['svm']['support_vectors']
yData = qsvm_res['svm']['yin']
qsvm_alphas = qsvm_res['svm']['alphas']

w = np.zeros(n_features)

for n in range(len(qsvm_alphas)):
    w += qsvm_alphas[n]*yData[n]*xData[n]
```

Thanks,

Matthias

Comment: I'm not sure if [this is the same QSVM](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.QSVM.html), but if it is, I don't see any `qsvm_res` anywhere, although there is a `qsvm_ret`